# Learning areas of intersections

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, geometry

I will try my best to make this question clear. I have many circles intersected randomly ( wireless communication application WSN) , i want to let each  circle knows the intersection area with its neighbors by learning from the events happen in  that region (intersection regions) . suppose , there are points ( in an intersection region) and those points can be input data to learn that area ,Is there any machine learning way that can help to  determine those areas using those events( the scattered points in 2D plane ) ? If there is , should we have a lot of points so that we can learn from them and use ML ? Can i use little data to learn a part of the area and predict the other part ( i.e using determined intersection points) . Sorry if i make you confused, because i am also so confused , it is a compulsory project i have to write about and complete it this month. Thank you very much.

> Block quote